# Burning Ubuntu ISO onto a CD

Tags: iso, cd-image

I've downloaded `ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` via Chrome. Once that was done, I wanted to burn it onto a CD but I can't find the .iso file.

When I opened the Downloads folder, the .iso extension is not there anymore, and it opens with **WinRAR** for unzipping. I tried unzipping and searching for any ISO files but no luck.

I'm trying to add Ubuntu onto VirtualBox on Windows 7 host OS. Please help.

Comment: "the .iso extension is not there anymore, and it opens with WinRAR for unzipping." Is this not strange? What opens with WinRAR if the ISO is not there? Do not unzip any iso. It needs to be "burnt" which is a special operation to create a Linux bootable disk. Did you try Chrome>Wrench icon>Downloads

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have ISO files associated with an application, such as power ISO or other, most of the time the system will see it as a zip file. You can use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/), to burn the ISO to disk, or [Virtual CloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) to mount the ISO.

Lets explain with an example.

You probably have the .ISO extension associated with WinRAR when it was installed.  the simplest way to get it burned onto a CD is to get [Free ISO Burner](http://www.freeisoburner.com/).  That will burn the file for you.  When you open the program after you install it, just click on open, browse to the file location (ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64), and then click on burn

[image]

Once that is done, make sure that you change the boot order, so you can boot from CD.

Answer (score 0):

There is no extension because you might have enabled "Automatically Hide Extensions"

It opens in WinRAR because ISO is also an archive format.

Though this forum is meant for Ubuntu you can check [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/865219) and learn how to unhide the extension.